# looking for a way to customize an iterator on std::map

Tags: c++, iterator

I am using a std::map in my code to store data. It is quite easy to access and/or modify the elements with iterator of the map but since I really need to suppress some operations (like ++, [], etc.) I don't know if it is true, but seems few articles recommend not to inherit the std::map directly so I am writing a wrapper instead.

```
class MyContainer
{
  private:
    std::map<int, int> data;

  public:
    int &operator[](int); // here we write the interface to control the behavior of accessing the data element
    void &operator++();
    void &operator--();
};
```

But this cause another issue. Actually, I am using iterator everywhere in the code to access/modify the elements. But after the map moved into the self-defined class, I can no longer use the iterator in the main program to handle the data. Someone recommend to write my own iterator but after reading several articles, it seems that people suggest to customize our own iterator by inheriting std::iterator. It seems straightforward but it still too abstract to me. I have two doubts

1) I am going to iterate map but my wrapper is not really a container. and to control the behavior of the following operations (++, --, []) on the map elements, I should have the self-defined iterator refer to MyContainer instead of map. It seems confusing to me because we need to advance map but the iterator refer to the wrapper instead. I don't know how to make it work, is there any example I can follow for similar case? Thanks.

2) I don't want the code to access the map element directly, hence, I have defined the operator in the wrapper as

```
int &operator[](int)
```

In above function, the returned reference depends on the input parameter, that is to say, for some cases, it could return a NULL reference instead of something refer to the element. But if a NULL returned, the following calling is no longer valid

```
data[3]++;
```

because data[3] could return a null reference. But how can I check if the returned reference is null or not before updating the element?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "NULL reference".

Comment: If I rewrite the operator[](int key) to return int * (pointer to the map element) depending on the key input. I could return NULL instead of the pointer of the element, right? So why it can't be NULL?

Comment: Pointers can be null. References can't.

Comment: I think you are better off with bounds checking in the accessors. Restricting `++` and so on is complicated, and changing the return type of `[]` makes your container look quite different to other standard library ones.

Comment: `void &operator++();` does not compile. And what is the semantics of incrementing a map?

Answer (score 3):

I think implementing special behaviour for the elements' `++` operators and so on is overkill. Likewise for the increment and decrement operations on the iterators. I think a good solution is simply to add bound checking to the `[]` accessors and throw an out of bounds exception when necessary. So, use the map's `begin()` and `end()` methods, and add bound checking to `[]`:

```
class MyContainer
{
  private:
    std::map<int, int> data;
  public:
    typedef std::map<int, int> MapType;
    typedef MapType::iterator iterator;
    typedef MapType::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef MapType::reference reference;
  public:
    iterator begin() {return data.begin();}
    const_iterator begin() const { return data.begin();}
    // and so on ...
    reference operator[](size_t i) {
      if (data.size()<=i) { /* raise exception here */ }
      return data[i];
    }
    const reference operator[](int) const { /* same as above */}

};
```

This has the advantage that the return types match those of standard library containers.

Comment: thanks. I also think of using the similar code. But the main problem on this code in my case is operator[] return the reference to the data element instead of back to the MyContainer. So someone might call that like MyContainer[3]++, which will directly increase the 3rd element in the map by the operation ++. But what I really need to control is the ++ operation itself.

Comment: @user1285419 I am not sure I understand, but if you don't want people to be able to increase the elements of the container via x[i]++ then you can provide a const verrsion of the operator only.

Comment: thanks. I apologize the confusing question. But the reason I want to control the access of element is I only allow people to modify the non-zero-value element. For example, if we have a map as following (3, 2), (4, 1), (6, 0), (7, 3), (9, 0). They can modify the element (3,2), (4, 1) and (7, 3) but not (6, 0) and (9, 0). Hence, mycontainer[3]=4 and mycontainer[4]++ are valid but mycontainer[6]++ should be ban. It seems that we cannot do that with above code since operator[] will return a reference to the value @ key in the map but we cannot overload the ++ or = operator for control

Answer (score 0):

You can make you "map" public, if you have need to iterate it.
Otherwise, don't provide the interface of iteration, do everything (which needs iteration) inside.